# fetching data from mysql database using php, Displaying it in a WYSIWYG form for editing

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a cms project that has to do with [bootstrap](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor.html) WYSIWYG form for inserting  and retrieving from database. The insert code works properly and the retrieve code works well as well, but does not work when I want to edit an article. When I click on the edit link  which is `<a href='index.php?page=edit&id=".$row['id']."'><span data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button><span></a>` it refers me to my edit page. On my edit.php page I have this code to select from database which is working well

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

if(isset($_GET['id']))

$id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM berita WHERE id=$id" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{
    $image= $row['gambar'];
    $title = $row['judul'];
    $description = ( $row['konten']);
    $time = $row['tanggal'];
}
?>
```

When I echo the value into their respective form type, it works well only that the Bootstrap based WYSIWYG does not echo any of the value, but if I change it to normal textarea, it works fine. Here is my code on edit.php page

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");


if(isset($_GET['id']))    
    $id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM berita WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))      
{
    $image= $row['gambar'];
    $title = $row['judul'];
    $description = ( $row['konten']);
    $time = $row['tanggal'];
}
?>
<link href="plugins/WYSIWYG/editor.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="plugins/WYSIWYG/editor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtEditor").Editor();
    });
</script>

<form name="my_form" action="action.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time"  value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>" disabled>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Article Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" placeholder="title" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >select categories</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="cat" name="cat">
            <option value="World">World</option>
            <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
            <option value="Politics">Politics</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
            <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
            <option value="Gist">Gist</option>    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Write Article </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor"><?php echo  htmlspecialchars($description) ;?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">upload image</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="myimage" id="myimage" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>

    </div>

    <button onclick=" $('#txtEditor').val($('.Editor-editor').html());" type="Publish" id="Publish" name="Publish" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Any help please?

Comment: SQL injections aren't done with tags so `strip_tags` doesn't help. You should use parameterized queries. Are there console errors when trying to output to the WYSIWYG?

Comment: which wysiwyg plugin you are using?

Comment: Do you have jQuery also in the <script> tags? `$(document).ready()` needs jQuery. When you open developer tools (google "developer tools" if you're not sure) do you get any errors in the console - if you don;t have jQuery you'll get a message that $ is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :p I made a javascript demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/x14vdkk0/1/

**If you can't set the value the root cause is on the multiples lines.**
Indeed, it you do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtEditor').Editor();
    $('#txtEditor').Editor('setText', 'My text with <strong>LineControl</strong> :)
  second line !'); // SECOND LINE IN ERROR !
});
```

You can see (console.log) the part `second line` is in error because javascript does not recognize this.

[image]

> **Solution: escape all carriage return**

## From the database

You have a beautiful function `json_encode` that will protect you from all issues of this kind and javascriptize your variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtEditor').Editor();
    $('#txtEditor').Editor('setText', <?php echo json_encode($description); ?>); 
});
```

> I din't forgotten the *quotes* around the php function. Why ? Because
> `json_encode` function will add the quote aroud your text. If you do a
> `json_encode('toto')` output will be `"toto"` ; If you do a
> `json_encode([key' => 'toto'])` output will be `{"key":"toto"}`

That's all :)

## Another solution:

For the textarea, use `htmlspecialchars($description)`

```
<textarea id="txtEditor">
  My text with:
  &lt;strong&gt;LineControl !&lt;/strong&gt;
</textarea>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $el = '#txtEditor';
    $($el).Editor();
    $($el).Editor('setText', $($el).val());
});
```

Comment: thanks this function json_encode fix it, but you missed your quote in your php it should  $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", '<?php echo json_encode($description) ;?>');. thumbs up.

Comment: HI :) Hum ... strange. `json_encode` will add automatically the missed quotes. If you do a `<?php echo json_encode('toto'); ?>` the output will be `"toto"`; If you do a `<?php echo json_encode(['key' => 'toto']); ?>` the output will be `{"key":"toto"}`

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier if you refer which plugin you are using for WYSIWYG in bootstrap. From your code, I figured it is https://github.com/suyati/line-control

In this case, you need to place the value using a setter, so you should re-write your declaration code for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtEditor").Editor();
    $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($description) ;?>");
});
</script>
```

And remove the php echo from your textarea

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the 'publish' button, as it appears you want to replace the content within the editor with it. It will change the value, but it will not be visible and it will not submit the form...

Hope it helps

Comment: Use this line instead of htmlspecialchars : -  $('#txtEditor').Editor("setText", "<?php echo addslashes($description);?>");

Comment: @Dero3376 corrected the code. Probably the plugin requires initialization before set the text

Comment: or you can get the content via ajax and settext the response data to the editor. it is asincronous and no need refresh the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){         
        <?php
        if($description){
        ?>
            $('#txtEditor').Editor("setText", "<?php echo addslashes($description);?>");
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    });
```

Ref: https://github.com/suyati/line-control/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

try echoing description out of textarea and check if its displaying anything. If not then you are not getting any value in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I do face this problem with some other plugin finally i found one not make problems here it is:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and here my part of script to load and store data to database:
for store data

```
$features = htmlentities($_POST['features'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

and for load data just echo the plug will do decoding

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="features" name="features"><?php echo $data['features']; ?></textarea>
```